# Как скачать файл с помощью telnet?

Tags: unix, telnet, linux

Как можно получить содержимое файла при помощи telnet?

Нашел вот [это](http://prog-school.ru/2010/02/skachaem-yandeks-telnetom), в конце там дается задание скачать картинку при помощи telnet, но у меня такое не получается. Прошу помощи более опытных и умных людей.

Comment: содержимое то вы получите, только еще получите и заголовки сервера http, их надо либо обрезать, либо не направлять в вывод. Первое можно сделать постпроцессингом, например на perl, второе делается с помощью expect например. только зачем вам такой изврат ?

Comment: да это я потом все сделаю, главное получить, но КАК ?!

Comment: тут где-то посередине картинка. зачем вам телнетом то это получать ?


    echo -e "GET /morda-logo/i/ya-logo.png HTTP/1.1\nHost: yandex.st\n"|while read a;do echo $a;sleep 1;done|telnet yandex.st 80

чем вас wget и curl не устроили ?

Comment: @eicto как я понимаю это баш скрипт ? не могли бы подкинуть статейки/книжки по нему, только недавно поставил linux и еще не въехал во все вещи… а и перенесите свой комментарий в ответы !

Comment: http://www.bash-scripting.ru/abs/chunks/ в ответы не буду переносить. т.к. это не нужно вообще делать телнетом.

Comment: @eicto но все же я не могу не отметить, что Вы помогли мне и еще и книжку подкинули!

Answer (score 2):

чтобы сделать http-запрос, обычно достаточно послать пару заголовков вида:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ya.ru
```

и две пустых строки после них, только после этого необходима небольшая задержка, достаточная для получения ответа. например, так (приведён и вывод команды):

```
$ { echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: ya.ru\n\n'; sleep 0.5; } | telnet ya.ru 80
Trying 93.158.134.3...
Connected to ya.ru.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 16:01:28 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Location: https://ya.ru/
Expires: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 16:01:28 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 16:01:28 GMT
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP ADM DEV PSD IVDo OUR IND STP PHY PRE NAV UNI"
Set-Cookie: yandexuid=9932749951461686488; Expires=Fri, 24-Apr-2026 16:01:28 GMT; Domain=.ya.ru; Path=/

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

тут запрашивается просто индексная страница (адрес указан после `GET` — просто `/`) сайта `http://ya.ru`. в данном случае мы получили ответ-перенаправление на `https://ya.ru`.

а вот так можно получить картинку по адресу `https://yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/apple-touch-icon/ru-76x76.png`:

```
$ { echo -e 'GET /morda-logo/i/apple-touch-icon/ru-76x76.png HTTP/1.1\nHost: yastatic.net\n\n'; sleep 0.5; } | telnet yastatic.net 80
Trying 178.154.131.215...
Connected to yastatic.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 16:05:06 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 734
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 13:08:05 GMT
ETag: "571e16b5-2de"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Cache-Control: public
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes

здесь идут бинарные данные, которые я не копировал

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

этот вывод можно перенаправить в файл:

```
$ { echo -e 'GET /morda-logo/i/apple-touch-icon/ru-76x76.png HTTP/1.1\nHost: yastatic.net\n\n'; sleep 0.5; } | telnet yastatic.net 80 > some.file
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

правда, в таком случае в файл попадёт и ответ сервера — все эти переданные сервером http-заголовки.

убрать их можно, например, «пропустив» через *sed*-программу, которая удалит все строки, начиная с самой первой и до первой пустой (пустой строкой заканчивается список заголовков):

```
$ { echo -e 'GET /morda-logo/i/apple-touch-icon/ru-76x76.png HTTP/1.1\nHost: yastatic.net\n\n'; sleep 0.5; } | telnet yastatic.net 80 | sed '1,/^$/d' > some.file
Connection closed by foreign host.
```